# Is it possible to access an entire asset catalog programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, asset-catalog

**Scenario:** One of many unique assets (e.g., 'one.xcassets', 'two.xcassets', ....)

**Goal:** To empty an entire specific asset into its respective array.

Ex: one.xcassets -> [UIImage]

Is this possible?

How?

Comment: What exactly do you need. To iterate over an asset catalog, or to delete all the assets from a given asset catalog?.

Comment: I've created multiple assets.xcassets, for photo sets.  I want to load all photos per asset into their respective arrays.

Comment: What do respective arrays mean? and how you will decide which respective arrays an image belong to?.

Comment: Each .xcassets contain a collection of related images; hence the different .xcassets.  For example: hawaii.xcassets, maui.xcassets, etc.   I merely want to load all members of each asset into there respective array for processing.